# JUnit assertArrayEquals

Tags: java, junit

I've written a method that returns an int[]. I want to create a test that ensures that when I run my method, passing, say, 10 to the method, that it returns an int[]{0,1,3,5,7}.

How can I do this? Maybe I'm just missing the proper syntax or should be using a different assert method...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JUnit4, you could use the `org.junit.Assert` class:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0,1,3,5,7}, someMethod(10));
```